# Асинхронное выполнение метода при обработке запроса

Tags: java, spring

В контроллере имеется метод возвращающий сумму двух чисел и при этом мы хотим отправить email:

```
@RequestMapping(value = PUBLIC_END_POINT+"/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Integer test(@RequestParam("a") Integer a, @RequestParam("b") Integer b) {
    mailService.sendTestMail(a, b);
    return a+b;
}
```

Т.к. задача отправки почты тяжеловесная, а пользователю не важен результат успешности отправки email, ему необходима лишь сумма чисел `a` и `b`, то хотелось бы просто вызвать отправку и не дожидаться отработки `sendTestMail()`.

Самое простое что пришло на ум - дернуть отправку в новом потоке:

```
@RequestMapping(value = PUBLIC_END_POINT+"/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Integer test(@RequestParam("a") Integer a, @RequestParam("b") Integer b) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mailService.sendTestMail(a, b);
        }
    }).run();

    return a+b;
}
```

Хотелось бы узнать насколько такое решение оптимально?(*и что самое интересное - данный поток все равно выполняется синхронно*)

Может быть есть какая то аннотация, которой можно пометить метод `sendTestMail()` что бы он выполнялся асинхронно?

Comment: В спринге есть аннотация @Async - http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async, которая запускает выполнение метода в отдельном потоке.

Comment: @learp, да, я пробовал помечать метод `sendTestMail()` данной аннотацией, но он все равно отрабатывал синхронно.

Comment: [Посмотрите тут пример](http://spring-projects.ru/guides/async-method/) , нужно добавлять у конфигурации аннотацию `@EnableAsync`

Comment: @MrFylypenko да, после добавления заработало, только выводил еще предупреждение - `No TaskExecutor bean found for async processing`, так что пришлось еще создать бин `threadPoolTaskExecutor`

Comment: можете оформить ответ

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResult.html

Comment: @etki спасибо, попробую вникнуть. а не подскажите, почему все таки вариант с новым тредом не прокатил, вроде же он должен вызываться асинхронно, или это на уровне спринга нельзя без `@EnableAsync`

Comment: А как вы поняли, что исполняемое в новом потоке исполняется синхронно?

Comment: @etki ну так логов наставил, и посмотрел по последовательности, получил что вызов `return a+b` происходил все равно после того как отработает тред с `sendTestMail()`

Comment: Это не значит синхронно, это значит только что строки были выведены в таком порядке. Новый поток мог вытеснить текущий из ядра процессора, например, и поэтому получился такой вывод, но никакой синхронности тут точно нет. Сам подход действительно так себе, потому что создавать новый тред каждый раз - не самая дешевая операция.

Comment: @etki может конечно быть, но на клиенте в `sendTestMail()` у меня `sleep` на 5 секунд, если бы это было лишь погрешностью вывода логов, то на клиенте я бы результат увидел практически мгновенно, однако я его получил как раз таки с этой 5-ти секундной задержкой...как будто в основном потоке был join

Comment: @etki аааа, только сейчас дошло - `run() != start()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Spring` позволяет асинхронное выполнение метода, для этого необходимо пометить вызываемый метод аннотацией `@Async`:

```
@Async
public void sendTestMail(a, b){ //реализация };
```

Для работы этой аннотации необходимо добавить аннотацию `@EnableAsync` в класс конфигурации и добавить бин `threadPoolTaskExecutor`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class SpringAsyncConfig {

    @Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    }
}
```